# Calculating line integration of a intersection of a paraboloid and a plan

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to solve this question:

> Calculate $\int_{\gamma} y\;dx + dy +2dz$ being $\gamma$ the intersection of a paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ with the plan $z = 2x + 2y - 1$. The way may be chosen that the projection of $\gamma(t)$, in the xy plane, go in the anticlockwise.

My try:

I found the equation of a circunference in the xy plane: $$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$$
After this, I parameterized the circunference and made his integral.

Parameterization:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{lcr} x & = & \cos{t} + 1 \\ y & = & \sin{t} + 1 \\ z & = & 2(\cos{t} + \sin{t} + 2) - 1 \end{array} \right.$$

$$\gamma(t) = (\cos{t} + 1, \sin{t} + 1, 2(\cos{t} + \sin{t} + 2) - 1) \\ \gamma \prime (t) = (\sin{t}, - \cos{t}, 2(\sin{t} - \cos{t})) \\ \begin{Vmatrix} \gamma \prime (t) \end{Vmatrix} = \sqrt{5 - 4\sin{2t}}$$

Integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} [(\sin{t} + 1) \sin{t} - \cos{t} + 2\cdot (2(\cos{t} + \sin{t} + 2) - 1)] \cdot \sqrt{5 - 4\sin{2t}}\; dt$$

After this, I tried to make a integral substitution but it results in 0. I got stuck in this part. My teacher said that the answer is $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct upto the point $\gamma(t) = (\cos{t} + 1, \sin{t} + 1, 2\cos{t} + 2\sin{t} + 3)$

Then $\gamma \prime (t) = (-\sin{t}, \cos{t}, 2\cos{t} - 2\sin{t})$

Please note this is line integral of a vector field, so we do not evaluate
$\begin{Vmatrix} \gamma \prime (t) \end{Vmatrix}$.

Vector field $ \vec F (\gamma(t)) = (1 + \sin t, 1, 2)$

The line integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} (1 + \sin t, 1, 2) \cdot (-\sin{t}, \cos{t}, 2\cos{t} - 2\sin{t}) \ dt$

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} (5 \cos t - 5 \sin t - \sin^2t) \ dt$

As integral of $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ over $2\pi$ is zero, integral reduces to,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} - \sin^2t \ dt = - \pi$

Comment: thank you very much. I was trying to solve this question in the scalar form. Now, I understand better this question.

Comment: you are welcome!